# Is there software which parses an xml file to see if all tags in it are ended?

Tags: xml

I get an exception in my J2ME application and the exception message is :

> `expected: END_TAG {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Body
>   (position:END_TAG
>   </{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}SOAP-ENV:Fault>@2:299 in
>   java.io.InputStreamReader@e5125d64)`

So I guess that my `wsdl` xml file has a tag that is not closed. So I want to know if there is software to parse an xml file for unclosed tags.

Comment: `Software` as an English word is never pluralized - it's always just `software` (and **never** `softwares`) - whether that means one program or application, or multiple programs/applications.

Comment: @pheromix: Judging from the error message you get, it seems the XML SOAP message is the problem (that's a SOAP fault). I don't see what that has to do with the XML of the WSDL. Debug your code and see where it breaks.

Comment: "Software as an English word is never pluralized" - I often see it pluralized, but only in spam. I think they do this to make life easy for spam filters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try pasting your XML code into this [XML validator](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp).

Comment: I validated my wsdl file from the xml validator and the result was that it is ok. So why do I get the exception when I run my app with accentuated letters from a MySQL column ?

Comment: Presumably that means that you don't have a missing close tag. I'm not familiar with wsdl files, but if you have a document definition (DTD) for that file format then see the section "Validate Your XML Against a DTD". Also, I'm not sure what you mean by "accentuated letters".

Answer (score 3):

For instance, [xmllint](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html) from [libxml and friends](http://xmlsoft.org/)

Answer (score 2):

Any XML parser checks that all tags are correctly closed. That's why you're getting an error message - it comes from an XML parser.

Comment: +1. Yes, and it's parsing the SOAP message not the WSDL.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to drop it on a webbrowser. It will show you if the xml file is valid.

---

If you need more you can use notepad++ with installed "Xml tools". (They can be installed via plugin menue) They include validation, pretty print ...